# How to load fileSystem in a hierarchyView?

Tags: c#, .net, file, filesystems, directory

I'm a GTA modder (single player, PC) and am working on an RPF archive Tool. I want to implement a feature, so that it extracts the content of a folder (a folder can contain subfolders).
I can't do that with one foreach as foreach only shows all subfolders of the current opened folder and not the subfolders of the subfolders.
So I need a way to browse all folders. Is there something existing already?
For example Windows' file system works similar. And adding folders to a hierarchyView is similar too (it's not what I want to do, but a very similar thing, that's why I tried to simplify the main question)

Are you guys able to help me? :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question : [How to use treeView to list the Files within sub Directories without showing the root directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21663060/4546874) has some code showing a way to populate a TreeView with files and folders including varying levels of subfolders, basically boiling down to:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   PopulateTree(@"C:\treeview", treeView1.Nodes.Add("I want to remove this node"));
}
public void PopulateTree(string dir, TreeNode node)
{
    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
    foreach (DirectoryInfo d in directory.GetDirectories())
    {
        TreeNode t = new TreeNode(d.Name);
        PopulateTree(d.FullName, t);
        node.Nodes.Add(t);
    }
    foreach (FileInfo f in directory.GetFiles())
    {
        TreeNode t = new TreeNode(f.Name);
        node.Nodes.Add(t);
    }
}
```