# C# How to use treeView to list the directories and subdirectories without showing the root directory?

Tags: c#, treeview

From

```
main folder
|_a
| |_b
| |_c
|_d
|_e
```

to

```
a
 |_b
 |_c
d
e
```

I want a treeview without the main folder. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663060/how-to-use-treeview-to-list-the-files-within-sub-directories-without-showing-the) but it seems that it's incredibly slow. When I first start the program it takes over a minute to load it. Without that code it opens instantly.

So, do you know any why to improve this code or another better code?

EDIT: **solved**.

Comment: Change it to populate the nodes with subdirectories only when the user expands them. Recursively enumerating every directory on the entire disk may take some time.

Comment: I already removed the part with adding the files. Actually I want all subdirectories of a specific directory, but without that directory itself included. The problem is that it's still very slow to process.

Comment: Do you know how many directories it's adding? Is it doing anything redundant? If it adds only on parent expand, then any size tree is manageable (provided folders have a halfway sane number of sub folders)

Comment: A bit over 600 in total (folders & subfolders). This main folder has around 250 subfolders and each one of them has folder has between 0 and 10 subfolders (usually 2).

Comment: That's all UI objects, so it's going to add up. I don't have a real intuition offhand about whether 600 should be mortally slow or not though.

Comment: How many levels are there? You need to load 2, so you know whether a expansion node is needed. So if you have 2 levels below the root, they will always all have to be loaded. To speed this up you can create the TreeNodes in memory before adding them wih one AddRange call.

Comment: But if loading the 2nd level is indeed the problöem you can try this: load only the 1st level and add one dummy node to each node. Then before expanding to this  dummy add the rest and remove the dummy..! - Either way, loading 600 nodes should be rather fast, unless you pull them in slowly, maybe over a slow line..

Comment: There is the main folder plus two other tiers. I updated the original post with the folders structure.

Comment: @TaW: There must be something wrong with that code. I found another one that loads the folder structure with the main folder included and it's much faster. But I don't need that main folder in the treeview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it looks real fast here. You can control whether all nodes are expanded or not.. You need to included the LINQ namspace (`using System.Linq;`)

```
// somewhere:
string yourRoot = "D:\\";
treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(getFolderNodes(yourRoot, true).ToArray());

private void treeView1_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode tn = e.Node.Nodes[0];
    if (tn.Text == "...")
    {
        e.Node.Nodes.AddRange(getFolderNodes(((DirectoryInfo)e.Node.Tag)
              .FullName, true).ToArray());
        if (tn.Text == "...") tn.Parent.Nodes.Remove(tn);
    }
}

List<TreeNode> getFolderNodes(string dir, bool expanded)
{
    var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dir).ToArray();
    var nodes = new List<TreeNode>();
    foreach (string d in dirs)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(d);
        TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(di.Name);
        tn.Tag = di;
        int subCount = 0;
        try { subCount = Directory.GetDirectories(d).Count();  } 
        catch { /* ignore accessdenied */  }
        if (subCount > 0) tn.Nodes.Add("...");
        if (expanded) tn.Expand();   //  **
        nodes.Add(tn);
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

If you are sure you always want to see all levels expaded from the start you can use this function and delete the `BeforeExpand` code:

```
List<TreeNode> getAllFolderNodes(string dir)
{
    var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dir).ToArray();
    var nodes = new List<TreeNode>();
    foreach (string d in dirs)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(d);
        TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(di.Name);
        tn.Tag = di;
        int subCount = 0;
        try { subCount = Directory.GetDirectories(d).Count(); } 
        catch { /* ignore accessdenied */  }
        if (subCount > 0)
        {
            var subNodes = getAllFolderNodes(di.FullName);
            tn.Nodes.AddRange(subNodes.ToArray());
        }
        nodes.Add(tn);
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

You call it as before:

```
string yourRoot = "D:\\";
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(getAllFolderNodes(yourRoot).ToArray());
Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
```

Comment: I tried it. There's a problem though: instead subdirectories I get ... (3 dots). I want to see the subdirs too. Also I got an error regarding .ToArray() and I removed .ToArray() from the code. I'm using also ExpandAll() because I want to see all dirs and subdirs without any additional clicking.

Comment: I'd like to see the treeview something like that: http://i.imgbox.com/jbhLsPSC.png 

The main folder that contains all these subfolders is not displayed.

Comment: While I did edit the code to a modified version it still requires the drilling down clicks. I'll add an expand all function later, if you're interested.

Comment: But if I use ExpandAll() at the end, the tree is not expanded?

Comment: I get this error: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061)

Comment: Have you included the namspace for LINQ? Also do note the new remarks (**) on expanding exfficiently!! Big difference for my D. drive. But it contains +46k  folders. I have now added a bool param to control the expanding..

Comment: Why did you put those "..."? As I said I need the whole folder structure at once, minus the main folder.

Comment: If you ran the code you should never have seen the '...' as they are deleted when expanding. Always fully expanding a file structure can lead to nasty delays, so the option to not expand all at the start is nice to have.. -  But you can try the second version which always expand the nodes.

Comment: Yes, this is! Thanks a lot.